# Showing GeoJSON result on Google Maps

Tags: geojson, google-maps, json, ajax

I have some points result query in MySQL database which is GeoJSON and I want to show these points on a Google map. I need to get this result with AJAX and deliver them to Google Maps. Can anybody write a code to do this?

Comment: It's not likely that *anybody* can write this code. It's also unlikely that anyone here will write it for you (GIS SE is not a coding service; it is a question/answer database compilation effort). What have you tried? What problem have you encountered?

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps Platform has [extensive documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer) on using GeoJSON data.

Although it is not a Google map, you could try looking into the [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) package which has [support for GeoJSON](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/) objects. You can then build the appropriate AJAX calls around it to get the data you need.

If you just want to look at the data visually (and are not really building a web service), [geojson.io](http://geojson.io/) is a great place to upload and inspect reasonably small geo files